# On Back press of second activity, 1st activity gets blank

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities, When I go back from 2nd activity (2nd activity is invoked by 1st activity) to 1st activity , 1st activity gets blank. I also tried to call **finish()** after **startActivity()**. It is directly going to the home activity. 2nd Activity contains a fragment.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();



        }
    }
```

Comment: We can't help you if you do not provide any code

Comment: You have to call fragment from activity.

Comment: You will have to provide more details to support your question

Comment: Please provide all lifecycle methods(onPause, onResume, etc...) of first activity.

Comment: You probably put your fragment to backstack...?!

Comment: I think that after you do a back press, you don't go to activity one, you just remove fragment from activity 2

Comment: I forgot to mention 1st Activity also has onActivityResult() for another activity @Aidin

Comment: Post the code of your `onResume()` in `Activity1`

Answer (score 0):

Just start activity using

```
startActivity(intent);
```

instead

```
startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode);
```

and don't override onResume or onActivityResult()

Answer (score -1):

If I right understand the question, solution you can found in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Setup parent activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application ... >
...
<!-- The main/home activity (it has no parent activity) -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" ...>
    ...
</activity>
<!-- A child of the main activity -->
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Enable go back arrow in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```